# Last item removed from RecyclerView but still visible on Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have [recyclerview](/questions/tagged/recyclerview) on my `Fragment`.When I am deleting the last item from `Recyclerview` it gets deleted but it is visible on Layout. I need to manually refresh the `Fragment` then it is gone. This happens only for deleting the last item otherwise delete the item from RecyclerView works fine.
This is code for calling Delete method using interface from AdapterClass

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private  TextView number;
    private  TextView people;
    private ImageView deleteReservation;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView, final OnEntryClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        number=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        people=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.people);
        deleteReservation=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        editReservation=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editReservation);
        deleteReservation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener!=null) {
                    int position = originalList.indexOf(filter.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.deleteReservation(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This is code for deleting item from RecyclerView

```
@Override
public void deleteReservation(final int position) {
    removePeople = current.get(position).getNoOfPeople();
    removeId = current.get(position).getReserveid();
    removeTime = current.get(position).getFullTime();
    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    confirm.setTitle("Confirmation");
    confirm.setMessage("Are you sure to cancel reservation ?");
    confirm.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            removeFromReservation();
            removeItem(position);
        }
    });
```

This is method to delete item.

```
 public void removeItem(int position) {
        current.remove(position);
         adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        //adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, current.size());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(current.size()==0){
            current.clear();
            getData();
        }

    }
```

Comment: call adapter.notifyitemremoved(originalList.size() -1);

Comment: you should add your adapter code (at least for initialization)

Comment: adapter.notifyitemremoved(originallist.size-1) not working. it should be in adapter class or in the Fragment Class.

Comment: 1) the onclick method is fired? 2) add the full adapter code pls

Answer (score 2):

try this function hope it works for you

```
public void removeItemAt(int position) {
    current.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, current.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass ItemView along with the position parameter in order to Invisible it. I have written my connect hopefully it will work for you!

```
listener.deleteReservation(position,itemView);

public void deleteReservation(final int position , View itemView){
.
.
.
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        removeFromReservation();
                                        removeItem(position,itemView); // there pass again
                                    }
}
```

Make ItemView invisible or Gone in this method...

```
public void removeItem(int position,itemView) {
        current.remove(position);
         adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        //adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, current.size());
        itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(current.size()==0){
            current.clear();
            getData();
        }

    }
```